# Check if file deletion was successful

Tags: ios, swift, delete-file

According to XCode documentation (alt-click), removeItemAtPath returns true or false. The below code however gives me the following error:

Cannot convert value of type '()' to specified type 'Bool'.

```
let result: Bool = try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(<my file path here>)
```

Is the documentation wrong? How do I check for successful deletion of the file? Will the execution of following code be skipped if the error is thrown in removeItemAtPath?

Example:

```
try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(<my file path here>)
doOtherStuff()
```

Will doOtherStuff be called if an error was thrown?

Comment: see documentation about do / try / catch pattern.

Comment: In Swift, the BOOL return value used in Objective-C is replaced with a Do/Try/Catch block. So in Swift `removeItemAtPath` throws, but in Objective-C `removeItemAtPath` returns a BOOL

Comment: if it succeeds, anything under your try will execute, if it fails, anything under your try will not execute, but if you have a catch, anything under catch will execute upon failure

Comment: Thank you, then its like I though. Good to know about the bools being replaced with try catch in Swift. I did read up on do / try / catch but all I read was about the old NSError class, not these old bool return values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will doOtherStuff be called if an error was thrown?

No. The whole point of `try` is that if it fails it exits immediately from the current scope. That is *why* you don't have to capture and test the result and/or an NSError pointer (and cannot do so).

Answer (score 0):

Per the comments, you want to use a Do/Try/Catch block.

```
 do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath("<my file path here>")
    } catch {
        print ("The file could not be removed")
    }
```

If the file is removed, the code in the try block will be executed.  If the file is not removed, the code in the catch block is executed.

For example, if you put print ("Success") in your try block, that print statement will execute if the file is successfully removed.

Likewise in the catch block, you can put whatever code you want to execute if the file is not removed. I put a simple print statement but you can put whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

here is a method that i use with try/catch:

```
func deleteFileFromDocumentsDirectory(fileName : String) -> () {

    // Optional 1: split file by dot "."
    let fullName = fileName.componentsSeparatedByString(".")
    let fileName = fullName[0];
    let fileExtension = fullName[1];

    let documentsFolder : String = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    let destinationPath = documentsFolder + "/" + fileName + "." + fileExtension
    // Optional 2: check, if file exits
    let fileExists = fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(destinationPath)

    if fileExists {
        do {
            try fileManager.removeItemAtPath(destinationPath)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not delete \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should remove `let error : NSErrorPointer = nil;` it's useless, the catch block generates the `error` constant itself.

Comment: @Eric D sure, you´re right. I removed it. U see everything ;-)